# Compare times of day without date

Tags: php, datetime

So it's possible to compare times with `<`, `>`, etc, but when used with `strtotime`, you get the unix timestamp so you can't compare the times independent of the dates.

What I'd like to do is be able to express something like:

```
$reference_time = "2010-01-01 18:00:00";
print strtotime("19:00:00") > strtotime($reference_time);
print strtotime("16:00:00") > strtotime($reference_time);
```

But I'd like the second expression to return `false` (since, ignoring the date, the time is less). What's the simplest way to do this? (Preferably without splitting the string)

Comment: This has been asked before, please use the search.

Comment: @hakra: I did look, but was unable to find anything. It seemed like a common need...

Comment: Problem is the number of (merely) duplicate date/time questions is that large, you can not even find the correct stuff nowadays fast. But I also found it easier to post an answer than searching :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) has a second parameter, too. Try:

```
$reference_time = "2010-01-01 18:00:00";
$absolute = strtotime($reference_time);

print strtotime("19:00:00", $absolute) > $absolute;
print strtotime("16:00:00", $absolute) > $absolute;
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/uG4bsxTH

Answer (score 1):

You could take the modulus of each Unix timestamp with respect to 86400 (the number of seconds in a day).

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: This is not how that works with UNIX timestamps. You can only count seconds, but the number of seconds in a day *vary*.

Comment: You're absolutely right, hakra. My answer was a little clever and a lottle wrong.

Comment: Well mathematically the idea was not that bad, however math is only a model and time is a measurement.

Comment: @Kiyura: fwiw, I thought it was pretty clever

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
print strtotime("19:00:00") > strtotime(explode(' ',$reference_time)[1]);
print strtotime("16:00:00") > strtotime(explode(' ',$reference_time)[1]);
```

You need **PHP 5.4** as mininum for above code to work.