# Comparing time from SQL database to PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I was trying to compare time from my SQL database to PHP. Let's say I have 22:00:00 (in 24hr format and GMT +8) in my database, which I have stored in `$time_start` variable in PHP and I am comparing it with the current time in PHP by `$time = date('H:i:s');` which is equal to let's say 21:00:00 (which is also in GMT +8) which I have also used `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');` in my PHP code. I have tried several possible solutions such as:

```
if (strtotime($time) < strtotime($time_start) {
echo "Your current time is less than the time start";
}
else {
echo "Your current time is greater than the time start";
}
```

and

```
if ($time < $time_start) {
echo "Your current time is less than the time start";
}
else {
echo "Your current time is greater than the time start";
}
```

and

```
$time_start = "22:00:00";
$time_start_1 = strtotime($time_start);
$time_start_2 = date('H:i:s', $time_start_1);

$time = date('H:i:s');
$time_1 = strtotime($time);
$time_2 = date('H:i:s', $time_1);

if (time_2 < time_start_2) {
echo "Your current time is less than the time start";
}
else {
echo "Your current time is greater than the time start";
}
```

However, none of it seems to be working. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: whats the `var_dump($time_start)` (the one from your sql) looked like? because, comparing string to actual time might be a bit problematic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare times of day without date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554310/compare-times-of-day-without-date)

Comment: It says string(8) "22:00:00" but it was stored in my database as time datatype.

Comment: @BagusTesa let me check if it solves my problem.

Comment: if you used `mysqli_fetch_array` (or the OOP variant), it will return an array of strings of the fetched rows. its stated in [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php#refsect1-function.mysql-fetch-array-returnvalues). which is why my suspicion was `$time_start` wasn't in proper data type to compare.

Comment: Maybe I can apply `strtotime($time_start)` to my `$time_start` to see if your suggested post will help me.